# Hosting mulitple websites on single tomcat 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat6, tomcat7, ubuntu-11.04

I have one domain hosted on cloud server. Let's say  o.com

Now i want to add a.com and b.com to same cloud server, for that , i added host entries inside server.xml as below,

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
  <Host name="a.com" appBase="webapps_a"></Host>
 <Host name="b.com" appBase="webapps_b"></Host>
```

(Note, Localhost was the orignal entry)

But , problem is , they both are pointing to o.com  and not to their respective domains/webapp directories

Comment: Did you point them from /etc/hosts ? also you may use <host>  <Context path="" docBase="hello" debug="0" privileged="true" /> </host> where hello is your app folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a Apache HTTP Server in front of tomcat. In Apache2, you can define different servers handling requests to different URLs in enabled-sites folder, then link to  different applications running on a single tomcat instance through a reverse proxy.

Comment: in my case, i have standalone tomcat running website